# How do I automatically connect VPN that includes Group?

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks, vpn

I'm trying to run a batch file or even use Task schedule in order to automatically start VPN (cisco).

The VPN works great when I run it manually...

I've tried rasdial name username password but it gives me 691 error (Remote Access error 691 - The remote connection was denied because the user name and password combination you provided is not recognized, or the selected authentication protocol is not permitted on the remote access server.)

task schedule seems to start but not finish connection.

My VPN include a Group which might cause the problem.
Is it possible that the Group that is not defined in Rasdial is the problem? how do I add the group to rasdial and/or task schedule?

[image]